# A Windows Program what tracks other Program activity, what kind of data is sent and received

Tags: monitoring

I'm looking for an app/program that can show another program full activity, such as what kind of data (text, numbers, hash, or Decrypted) has been sent, where data is sent and/or received data from an internet source or local source.

Comment: For which operating system? Must it be gratis, or do you have a budget?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a browser app, obviously you can just hot F12 for developer tools & look in the network app.

If not, then WireShark, as answered by @gfdsweds will certain do the job. It's that we ever use in the office/lab. It's free, powerful and can also decode a lot of common data formats.

Wireshark can be a little overwhelming, though, so you might want to look at [Fidller](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), which is free, cross-platform and easy to use.

If you want to test your own programs, instead of spy on others, then use the renouned [Postman](https://www.postman.com/api-platform/meet-postman/).

Btw, you are going to have problems with

> where data is sent and/or received data from an internet source or local source.

because Windows sends local HTTP traffic (localhost / http:127.0.0.1) directly and does not use the TCP/IP stack, which is what all of the other tools hook into.

BUT, there is hope. Read these & search for more:

- [Simple Way to Monitor Localhost Network Traffic on Windows](http://www.labviewcraftsmen.com/blog/simple-way-to-monitor-localhost-network-traffic-on-windows)
- [How can I see 127.0.0.1 traffic on Windows using Wireshark?](https://superuser.com/questions/508623/how-can-i-see-127-0-0-1-traffic-on-windows-using-wireshark)
- [Wireshark localhost traffic capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847168/wireshark-localhost-traffic-capture)
- [A free HTTP sniffer for all traffic to localhost websites made from whatever client](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9711/a-free-http-sniffer-for-all-traffic-to-localhost-websites-made-from-whatever-cli) has no accepted answer, but a few good links. Caveat, the question is 7 years old.
- simplest might be [Beginner’s Guide to Windows 10 built-in Packet Sniffer ‘PktMon’](https://www.helpmegeek.com/windows-10-packet-sniffer-pktmon-guide/), but I have not used it, so have no idea how good it is.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but have heard good things, for internet sources I think [glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/) would fulfill that for windows.

Comment: Glasswire does not track what programs/apps are sending/receiving.. :/

Comment: "Detect hidden threats with GlassWire's Firewall" is what it's webpage says at the top.